# Socket.io, https, and express continuous connect/disconnect loop

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to use socket.io, express, and https together on node. When socket.io connects it immediatley disconnects, re-connects again and loops. The problem can be re-created using the following code...

Server

```
var app = express();
var server = https.createServer(sslOptions, app)
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
app.use(express.static('./public'));
server.listen(port, function(){});
```

Client

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('https://testdomain.com', { secure: true });
</script>
```

Error

```
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized uBDQXqTmgbJzm-lnSWsm
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/uBDQXqTmgbJzm-lnSWsm
debug - set heartbeat interval for client uBDQXqTmgbJzm-lnSWsm
debug - client authorized for
debug - websocket writing 1::
warn  - websocket parser error: reserved fields must be empty
info  - transport end (undefined)
debug - set close timeout for client uBDQXqTmgbJzm-lnSWsm
debug - cleared close timeout for client uBDQXqTmgbJzm-lnSWsm
debug - cleared heartbeat interval for client uBDQXqTmgbJzm-lnSWsm
debug - discarding transport
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it, although I tried with `io.connect('', { secure : true })` to let `socket.io` autodiscover the server. You're not working through a proxy?

Comment: No proxy or anything. I get the same problem when doing autodiscovery too. Only have this problem when using https though.
This is the full source code I was using to test... https://gist.github.com/m1sta/5732497

Comment: I just tried to look into the socket.io source to work out what is happening... I've noticed that when using https, line 509 of hybi-16.js (Parser.prototype.processPacket) get's hit immediately after connection with the data parameter set to 129. This is where the error is thrown. With http, this line is doesn't appear to be hit until the first heartbeat, at which time the data parameter is set to 71 and all works fine.

Comment: Is there any chance that we're getting different results as a result of different socket.io and/or express versions, different certificate details, different openssl installs, or different versions of node? I'm using Node v0.10.9 on Winx64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by uninstalling Node v0.10.9 and installing v0.10.10.

Comment: Ah, good to hear :) I forgot that one of the Changelog entries for 0.10.10 was: *"socket.io works again"*